# Ext.net:PreviousPage.FindControl issue

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

I have main page something like this.

```
<ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" Theme="Gray" />
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <ext:Panel runat="server" ID="anaPanel" Title="OSO" Icon="Car">
        <TopBar>
            <ext:Toolbar runat="server" Layout="FitLayout">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Floating="false" Layout="HBoxLayout" ShowSeparator="false"
                        AnimCollapse="true" Cls="horizontal-menu">
                        <Defaults>
                            <ext:Parameter Name="MenuAlign" Value="tl-bl?" Mode="Value" />
                        </Defaults>
                        <Items>
                            <ext:MenuItem ID="MenuItem1" runat="server" Text="" Icon="Group">
                                <Menu>
                                    <ext:Menu ID="Menu2" runat="server">
                                        <Items>
                                            <ext:MenuItem Text="new card" Icon="GroupAdd">
                                           <DirectEvents>
                                           <Click OnEvent="AddNewCart_Click"></Click>
                                           </DirectEvents>

                                            </ext:MenuItem>
                                            ...............
                                            ...............
                                            </ext:Panel>
 <ext:Window runat="server" ID="MyWindow" Hidden="true"></ext:Window>
    </form>
```

My maninpage codebehind something like this.

```
 protected void AddNewCart_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {

        string path = "Pages/Kart.aspx";
        Window win = CreateWindows(MyWindow,Icon.Group,path,"new card", 420, 500);
        //private Window CreateWindows(Window Mywindow , Icon ic,string path,string Title, int Heigh, int With){......};
       //I get the MyWindow and pass some values and turn it back.
        win.Render(this.Form);
        win.Show();
    }
```

inside the Kart.aspx I have some buttons,my first question is ,how can I close this window .I put a button to close the this window(window which loaded Kart.aspx) ,here are the some way how I did.but none of them didnt work.

1-

```
 if (PreviousPage != null)//previouspage come as a null.
            {


                Window wnd = PreviousPage.FindControl("MyWindow") as Window;
                wnd.Close();
            }
```

2-

```
 Window wnd =   Parent.Page.FindControl("MyWindow") as Window;
  wnd.Close();
```

3-I also tried to make MyWindow as public inside mainpage and try to reach it from Kart.aspx,but also didnt work
  my second question is ,how can I pass the parameters between the those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the client side by calling

```
    window.parent.Ext.getCmp('MyWindow').close();
```

**Edit**

the closest to a code behind call is to use

```
    btnClose.AddScript("window.parent.Ext.getCmp('MyWindow').close();");
```

**Edit 2**

if you code is more complex like reloading a grid or modifying forms, you do the following:

**Code-Behind**

```
    X.Call("ReloadGrid");
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function ReloadGrid() {
                var grid = window.parent.Ext.getCmp('GridId');
                //grid reloading code
    }
```

Comment: is there anyway to do that from codebehind.plus,what "getCmp" exactlly doing in this example,thank you

Comment: ok thank you so much it works fine but ,is there any other solition to reach the parentpage controll,as I have grids inside mainpage,which when I add the new element inside the ifame,I have to always reload the gridviews,

Comment: @user2460637 you will have to do it from JavaScript, and to call the JavaScript method from code-behind, you can use X.Call("methodName");

Comment: can u give me a concrete example about the last comment,thank you

Comment: hmm,I see thank you so much,can u take a look at this question as well,I posted it also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589313/ext-net-parent-ext-net-directmethods-newcard-click

Comment: dera friend last thing I wanna ask you,u said function ReloadGrid() {
                var grid = window.parent.Ext.getCmp('GridId');
                //grid reloading code
    } something like this.how I can grid loadind,I try"window.parent.Ext.getCmp('MySTORE').reload();but didnt work,I also added onread properties my store to load the data from code behind like this, mystore.DataSource()=bll.getCustomer();mystore.DataBind();how Can I fire this function,thank you so much again

Comment: @user2460637 this question is expanding, please put it in a new question, and include the both the original data load code and the refresh code

Comment: yes yes u are right.so that I post my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669862/ext-net-loading-2-child-page-and-reach-from-one-child-to-another