# Ext.Net: parent.Ext.net.DirectMethods.NewCard_Click();

Tags: ext.net

I have a project.When I click the button inside mainpage, loading newcard.aspx file.inside this file I have a button something like this,

```
  <ext:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Ekle" Icon="GroupAdd">
     <Listeners>
     <Click Handler="parent.Ext.net.DirectMethods.NewCard_Click();"></Click>
     </Listeners>
     </ext:Button>
```

NewCard_Click();methon defined inside the mainpage.aspx.(which loadind anaother aspx file)
but this event not fired,Did I miss something?Should I add another something?

Comment: which version of ext.net are you using?

Comment: ext.net 2.2 latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier versions used

```
    Ext.net.DirectMethods.MethodName()
```

Which would make

```
    window.parent.Ext.net.DirectMethods.MethodName()
```

The correct answer, however it seem that changed in the latest version, so the answer is

```
    window.parent.App.direct.MethodName()
```